# How to solve `Type 'string[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.` in the best way possible?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
export type GameObj = {
  id: string
  game_type: string
  observations?: string[] // could add string[] | undefined, warning would go away
  note?: string // | undefined
}

const GameCard: React.FC<GameObj> = ({
  id,
  game_type,
  observations,
  note
}) => {
  const GameMap = new Map(Object.entries(gameDictionary))
  return (
    <GameCardContainer key={id}>
      <h3>{gameMap.get(game_type)}</h3>
      {note?.trim() && <h4>Note: {note}</h4>}
      {observations?.map((obs) => ( <h4>{obs}</h4>))}
    </GameCardContainer>
  )
}
```

Then, I'm using this component in another file this way

```
 <GameCard
   id={id}
   game_type={game_type}
   observations={observations} //gets highlighted
   note={note} // gets highlighted
/>
```

For `observations` and `note`, I get highlights such as:

```
- Type 'string[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
- Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

This data can indeed be `undefined`. I'm wondering if the 'correct' way is really to add `| undefined` to the type declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is indeed that your 'observations' prop is defined as of type `string` but you actually assign a `string | undefined` type variable to it. it that case you have two options:

**First Option - Your Suggestion**

defining `observations` as a possibly undefined value (you should choose this option if a situation when it is undefined is a "valid" situation which you expect - the GameCard component is supposed to know how to "deal" with undefined `observations`.

**Second Option**

before sending the value, you can check if its value is not undefined (and only send the prop if it is not undefined), or in shorthand you can use an `||` operator to use as a "fallback/default value" like this

```
observations={observations || []}
```

in this case I'm sending an empty array as a default value (if observation evaluates to false)

consider the difference between the two options (the second means that `undefined` is not an applicable value.

Comment: am I right to infer that what I'm doing (adding `| undefined`) is your First Option? The app indeed waits for observations to be undefined at times

Comment: oh, I misunderstood (thought you ment adding `| undefined` to your interface declaration). I edited my answer